# Transfer Object by using NamePipe [Inter-Process Communication] VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, named-pipes, inter-process-communicat

So far i have done the part that able to let me transfer text between the sender & receiver. Is there anyway to transfer an object by using namepipe? eg. arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vb.net you can also do this like C ….

Use serialize object and convert it to byte array transfer it and Deserialize on other end

Serialize

```
Dim BytArray() As Byte
Using MS As MemoryStream = Memory.Serialize(_Object)
     BytArray = MS.GetBuffer()
End Using
```

Deserialize

```
Dim _Return As objType = Nothing
Using MS As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(BytArray)
    _Return = Memory.Deserialize(Of objType)(MS)
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about .NET or VB usage with named pipes but in Visual C++ I would pack the raw data from the array or object into a byte array and write this to the pipe. After reading this out of the pipe at the other end I would then rebuild the array or object from the raw data.